# Spring MVC 3 Hibernate JPA Annotations onetomany and manytoone relationships cascade delete

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

I have the following entities and I have to delete the ServiceRegistration and ServiceChannels entries when I delete the ServiceRegistration record. But now, if I delete a record in serviceregistration, it delete the records in channel which is metadata table.

ServiceRegistration.Java

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "ServiceChannel", joinColumns = {
 @JoinColumn(name="serviceid", unique = true) 
 },
 inverseJoinColumns = {
 @JoinColumn(name="channelid")
 }
 )

 private List<Channels> channelsInvolved;

     public List<Channels> getChannelsInvolved() {
    return channelsInvolved;
  }

public void setChannelsInvolved(List<Channels> channelsInvolved) {
    this.channelsInvolved = channelsInvolved;
  }
```

ServiceChannels.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column private int servicechannelid;    

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "serviceid")
private ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "channelid")
private Channels channels;
```

Channels.java >> contains meta-data

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column private int channelid;
@Column private String channelname;

@Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Channels) {
            final Channels other = (Channels) obj;
            if (other.getChannelid() == getChannelid()) {
                return true;
            }
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

Please help me how to do cascade delete in this entity relation.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't want to get channels deleted when deleting a ServiceRegistration, you should do:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "ServiceChannel", joinColumns = {
 @JoinColumn(name="serviceid", unique = true) 
 },
 inverseJoinColumns = {
 @JoinColumn(name="channelid")
 }
 )

 private List<Channels> channelsInvolved;
```

In your service registration (disable cascading).

Also, if you want to get your ServiceChannel removed when you delete a ServiceRegistration, you have to configure the relationship in the ServiceRegistration side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="serviceRegistration", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) // Edited to specify the owning side of the relationship
private List<ServiceChannel> serviceChannels;
```

Comment: I am getting this error..Foreign key (FK47A18582B04FBB38:mcp_service_mcp_servicechannel [serviceChannels_servicechannelid])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (mcp_servicechannel [serviceid,channelid])

Comment: I edited the answer to add the owning side of the relationship (mappedBy attribute). This is necessary in the OneToMany relationship.

Comment: I did the changes as you said, when I delete any serviceregistration without any servicechannels,it's working fine. But If I have any servicechannel for any serviceregistration, its throwing 'Could Not Delete the Record!!!Batch update returned unexpected row count from ....'. I see the query generated by hibernate as 
Hibernate: delete from mcp_servicechannel where serviceid=?
Hibernate: delete from mcp_servicechannel where servicechannelid=?